# Where can I find a Graphql API to integrate with my flutter app

Tags: flutter, graphql

This is the first time I am working with graphql so I have little understanding on how it works.

I have been assigned a task to develop a news API using graph_ql API. The following is the API I have been provided with:

```
Authorization:
"x-hasura-admin-secret": "some_secret_key_given_here"

query getNews {
  news {
    title
    url
    publishedAt
    author
    content
    description
    h_id
    source
    urlToImage
  }
}
```

I am stuck on how to approach this or even how to get started. I could really use some help on how  can go about this and get some guidance. As this is the first time I am working with graphql I have no idea on how to make this work.

Comment: Please use this flutter plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter

Comment: It is not so complicated, you can use some existing packages on Flutter, but if you are learning then it's better to use `http` package, How? go to this [Postman tutorial](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/graphql/).

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Actually I have been limited to using graphql_flutter package.

Comment: @HardikMehta I have gone through the documentation for that package as that is the one I am required to use. However, my main concern is not about the package. I have gone through some tutorials and learnt about it and graphql. My main concern is about where can I get the data source from. Like one tutorial I watched used an API endpoint that had information about continents and countries. Where can I get one for news as mentioned in the above API? I need to put something in the HttpLink variable so where can I refer to for that? That is my main concern here.

Comment: data source is something that you have hosted on server and you have graphql is also over there. and database is also there this way its work

Comment: Right. Are you aware of any publicly hosted data sources that I can use for my case? Such as this one; https://countries.trevorblades.com/